# The 'use' attribute is not supported in this context. c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to use `ReadXmlSchema` to read xsd file with C#.
But I meet a problem when try to read the xsd file. I got the error message

> The 'use' attribute is not supported in this context.

Actually the xsd contain attribute `use="required"`.

```
<xs:attribute name="sch" type="xs:string" use="required"/>

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXmlSchema(@"C:\Schema\Schema.xsd");
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only time you will get this error message is when you defined the attribute global. You can have ***use*** only when the attribute is part of a content model.